A Chinese martial arts movie with swords acting like guns/arrows
I saw a Chinese martial arts movie back in 2011 or 2012.  I don't remember the whole plot of the movie but as much as I remember, there was a kingdom and an evil martial arts lord comes to the kingdom and topples the govt. and captures the king and his family.
The two main heroes of the movie try to fight with the evil lord but are easily defeated. They approach their master who tells them that if one of them took a bath in a pool of dark magic he might have enough power to defeat the evil lord. One of them agrees but turns evil himself so the other guy now tries to train himself more (without the dark magic) so that he can kill the evil lord and bring back his friend. That's all I remember about the movie plot.
One of the major things in the movie was that the swords in the movie were more like guns\arrows. You could kill someone with your sword even if you are 100 meters away from someone. 
If you know the movie name please tell me. I really want to watch that movie again. Thanks in advance.

Sounds like The Storm Warriors from 2009, the sequel to The Storm Riders from 1998.

Based on the comic book series "Fung Wan" and directed by The Pang Brothers comes the incredible story of two friends, Wind and Cloud, who find themselves up against a very powerful warlord intending to invade their country. In order to protect their land these two friends seek the help of the all-powerful master. Through extensive training Wind and Cloud expose themselves to the "evil" ways to increase their powers of element. When the intensive battle begins their friendship will be tested when one finds it hard to be righteous and easy to be evil.

Wind turns evil after wading in a pool of dark magic, and swords are often used as projectiles:



